# shortcut for showing and selecting mysql without using the mysql_fetch_array to every variable

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a shortcut for showing and selecting mysql without using the `mysql_fetch_array` to every variable?

```
<?
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpp WHERE section='1' game='1'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  {
    $s1g1 = $row['score'];
  }
  $s1g2;$s1g3;$s1g4;$s1g5;
?>
```

Should I keep adding the `$result` to every statement just to show it or is there a shortcut?

Comment: Haven't they explained arrays yet?

Comment: sorry no this is for some extra grades :D can i not repeat the WHERE over and over again for every distinct variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append the result to a variable you can do so using period concatenation:

```
$s1g1 .= $row['score'];
```

If you wish to save the data for use later, you can store it in an array:

```
$array[] = $row[score];
```

Also, please stop using `mysql_` functions. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: sorry did not make it clear enough not repeating WHERE for every variable
example WHERE section 1 game 1 , where section 2 game 2

Comment: @DasJavilinar You mean using the [`IN` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)? `... WHERE section IN (2, 3, 4) ... `

Comment: example : 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpp WHERE section='1'
 game='1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
$s1g1 = $row['score'];
  }
 
 
 

not repeating the statement WHERE over again

Comment: @DasJavilinar - You totally misled us by making it a PHP question. SQL is an entirely different language. The fact that you can use PHP to issue SQL queries doesn't change this fact.

Comment: @DasJavilinar Yes, use `IN`. `... WHERE section IN (1, 2) AND game = 1 ... `

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario sorry im new to this language stuff

Comment: @njk example for $s1g1 where section is 1 and game is 1 and for $s1g2 where section is 1 and game is 2 like this is there a shortcut not to use where again ty for answering

Comment: @njk thanks for answering not gonna use array though really hard time knowing what to do with it thank you anyway :D

Comment: @DasJavilinar I recommend you follow [Jon Skeet's guide](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write a good question.